# Integrate mobile app with Kendo mobile UI , angularjs and topcoat

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile, angular-kendo, topcoat

I have started an android app development.

1. I want to integrate **Kendo Mobile UI** with **Angularjs** and **Topcoat** . But  I am getting confused with all this. Please help me to understand the implementation of this thing.
2. Also I am confused with the fact that is the implementation of **Angularjs** and **Kendo UI** is same as the implementation of **Angularjs** and **Kendo Mobile UI** ?

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend checking this blog post: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/announcing-support-for-kendo-ui-mobile-with-angularjs/

Comment: This is quite helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your AngularJS/KendoUI concern, the Telerik resource linked here should be helpful to devs looking to optimally use AngularJS functionality within Kendo UI Mobile. AngularJS documentation and integration methods were updated in late 2014: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/angular/sushi-angular-tutorial